# How to create the same table in 2 SQLite databases without typing schema twice?

Tags: sqlite, create-table

I have SQLite databases `db1` and `db2`. I need identical tables in each: `publications`. How can I write a `.sql` file where I don't need to duplicate `create table`? Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE
  IF NOT EXISTS db1.publications,
  IF NOT EXISTS db2.publications(
    id TEXT,
    content TEXT
    ... a bit long...
);
```

Comment: If you do it from command line, [here is an instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832802/sqlite3-dump-schema-into-sql-file-from-command-line). To do it from software, you should specify approx which language you use. [Example from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996394/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-schema-of-a-database-from-within-python).  You should then just add the "if not exists..." part and run for each database.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working way:

```
CREATE TABLE users.drafts AS SELECT * FROM main.events WHERE 0;
```

Comment: This does not create an exact duplicate of the original table because it does not copy the definitions of the primary key, foreign keys, constraints and indexes.

Comment: @forpas You're right, but for my specific problem it does the job.

Comment: @forpas Do you know a way to clone database *including* primary key? Thanks.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to export the db as .sql file and execute it. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832802/sqlite3-dump-schema-into-sql-file-from-command-line and its accepted answer and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643611/execute-sqlite-script